# Does a 14 Year old Bryant Geothermal HP need replacing when the Scroll compressor goes to ground?

Tags: electrical, hvac

14 years ago we installed 2 Bryant Geothermal Heat Pump Units in a 2 zone home.  Downstairs was a single 2 stage unit (Air Handler & Compressor Combo) in the crawl space, and the upstairs unit is a split unit (Air Handler in attic and Compressor in the Garage).

Downstairs has been trouble free. Upstairs air handler fan motor went out 3 years ago, fixed in 2 days, but now the Scroll compressor in the garage is not just tripping the 40 Amp breaker, but the whole houses 200 Amp service.

Right now, the HVAC tech is starting a pissing match with the electrician he recommended that we call that there has to be something wrong with the main panel because the 30 amp compressor should not blow the main 200 amp panel at the same time it blows the 40 amp HP circuit.
I looked at the manufacturers electrical spec plate and it says the garage unit is a 30 Amp, but manufacturer also recommends a 50 Amp breaker, which they did not put in at install.

Question 1: Would this cause the main to blow?

HVAC tech says that since compressor grounded out that the entire unit (both parts) needs to be replaced, because of freon contamination (410A) and fact that Copeland does not make same compressor (found a replacement Compressor code, so that is a bit untrue).
Rationale is that the replacement compressor would fail. I asked if he could flush the lines clean and he said no, but I found a whole procedure for this on Contracting Business.com I do not think he has even performed an acid test yet; so:

Question 2: Do I need to find a reputable tech that can & will do a thorough line flush and Compressor replacement or are we stuck getting a new unit?

Which brings me to Question 3; is 410A on it's way out?  ie, if a new system, what refrigerant is best?

Comment: A quick review of search results indicates that R410A is indeed being phased out at present.

Comment: The smaller breaker should usually blow/trip first, but this is not a guarantee.  It will depend on which breaker trips faster, the different ages of breakers, and a few other factors.

Comment: All breakers are same age as house 30 years. When they installed the Geothermal they used the existing breaker that was there for the old outside tower

Comment: If you are using a substantial amount of power in the house already, then it is possible that the house breaker would go past its capacity, on a surge from the HVAC.

Comment: I think you should get a second opinion.

Comment: Getting other quotes/inspections is a good idea since this is not cheap.  Local regulations might require a full replacement because of the R410A.

Comment: 14 years old is not old enough to replace the entire system.  Replacement compressors should exist.  An electrician should sort the breaker sizing.

Comment: The electrician that the Bryant dealer (original installer) recommended found nothing wrong with the breakers, yet the Bryant dealer wanted to continue to nit pick that point. He is the one who said I would need a new system because of contamination of the oil.